# Access deployment id of vertx verticle from outside the inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes, vert.x

Hi i have deployed vertx  verticle like this  and now i want the asynchResult access this inner class. I have gone through many posts but didnt find any solution for that.

```
container.deployVerticle("com.demo.vertx.FirstVert", snmp_trap_listener_count, new AsyncResultHandler<String>() {
                public void handle(AsyncResult<String> asyncResult) {
                    if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                        System.out.println("The verticle has been deployed, deployment ID is " + asyncResult.result());
                    } else {
                        asyncResult.cause().printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                });
```

Please help to resolve this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guy's i got my answer . I have just made a setId local  method which takes AsynchResult as parameter and from inside inner class passed asynchResult to this method. So i got values in this method.

```
private void setDeployIds(AsyncResult<String> asyncResult){
          System.out.println("Deployment ID :" +asynchResult.result());
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the deployment ID as a result from the asynchronous handler like this:

```
container.deployVerticle("foo.ChildVerticle", new AsyncResultHandler<String>() {
public void handle(AsyncResult<String> asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
        System.out.println("The verticle has been deployed, deployment ID is " + asyncResult.result());
    } else {
        asyncResult.cause().printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

});

If you undeploy a verticle all of his children will be undeployed as well. Undeploying a verticle works like this:

```
container.undeployVerticle(deploymentID);
```

Comment: As you can see in my code ...i have used this verticle as starter verticle and this get deployed by command vertx run <verticle> on command prompt ...so once deployed how can i redeploy it by as you have posted container.deployVerticle(.....);